# Zapier question: Stripe to Slack differentiate between sub new and sub reactivation

Tags: stripe-payments, slack, zapier

I have a zapier question. How can i distinguish between new & reactivation stripe subscriptions in a slack channel? i'm experimenting with data points but i can't distinguish between brand new sub signs up and sub's that were created due to a previous recent cancellation.

many thanks,

Comment: Which Stripe events are you listening for in your Zapier task?

Comment: Hi Jonathan, thanks for responding! I'm using the 'New Event' (like dispute sub or transfer) trigger and then the Set Up trigger is 'New Customer Subscription Signup'

Comment: Got it. There'll be no way to differentiate those Subscription events between what is truly a new subscriber and what is a returning customer (from a prior cancellation). You'll need to track that data yourself, perhaps using the `metadata` [parameter](https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/create#create_subscription-metadata) when creating the subscriptions.

Comment: Ah ok great! Thank you very much for your insight @JonathanSteele - much appreciated!